# D2L Adobe Connect Integration - seminar rooms

Tags: desire2learn

We have a prospective client asking to have Adobe Connect/Desire2Learn integration. They currently have seminar rooms created in Adobe Connect, but the D2L integration creates a new room under the meeting tab, not a reoccurring room with the same url as the original seminar created with Adobe Connect. Is there anyway a developer could determine how these meetings are created with the D2L? Does it need Valence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Connect integration is enabled through a D2L Middleware Product we call Online Rooms (or IPSCT -- Integration Pack for Synchronous Communication Tools).

This integration is fully enabled through customer based configuration. It does NOT use Valence at all. Or, more accurately, there are no Valence API's exposed associated with this product.

Here is a link to D2L's Online Rooms documentation:

https://documentation.desire2learn.com/en/Online%20Rooms%20%28IPSCT%29%20Administration%20Guide%202.2

Comment: Right, so I understand IPSCT and Valence are two different animals. But IPSCT with regards to Adobe Connect seems to have nothing to do with seminar rooms. And it seems it uses Connect meetings to do most of its integration. Our client is asking for seminar rooms to be linked too. That is why I was looking at custom widgets or Remote Plugins through Valence as a way to give us a way to create our own tools. Is this accurate, or is there another approach we should take to get seminar rooms viewed in D2L?

Comment: A Remote Plugin approach (which uses Valence calls) would be a very solid approach for this form of integration. My initial reaction would be that a Quicklink Remote Plugin would be a great way to implement this form of integration.

Comment: Paul, we are going with your recommendation for now. Thanks.